# Java Check-Style- Rules

Tags: java, checkstyle

I am using Java 11, Maven. During the verify in lifecycle I get an error "There are 2 errors reported by Checkstyle 8.29 with config/checkstyle-checker.xml ruleset." . To be honest I don't know how to start and where should I look for check the details or specific description. I made some changes in the default version of checkstyle file: FinalParameters I switched it off, HiddenFiles and maximum lenght of characters in one line has been modified. Here is my CheckStyle -Config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC
        "-//Checkstyle//DTD Checkstyle Configuration 1.3//EN"
        "https://checkstyle.org/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">


<module name="Checker">
    <!--
        If you set the basedir property below, then all reported file
        names will be relative to the specified directory. See
        https://checkstyle.org/5.x/config.html#Checker

        <property name="basedir" value="${basedir}"/>
    -->
    <property name="severity" value="error"/>

    <property name="fileExtensions" value="java, properties, xml"/>

    <!-- Excludes all 'module-info.java' files              -->
    <!-- See https://checkstyle.org/config_filefilters.html -->
    <module name="BeforeExecutionExclusionFileFilter">
        <property name="fileNamePattern" value="module\-info\.java$"/>
    </module>

    <!-- https://checkstyle.org/config_filters.html#SuppressionFilter -->
    <module name="SuppressionFilter">
        <property name="file" value="${org.checkstyle.sun.suppressionfilter.config}"
                  default="checkstyle-suppressions.xml"/>
        <property name="optional" value="true"/>
    </module>

    <!-- Checks whether files end with a new line.                        -->
    <!-- See https://checkstyle.org/config_misc.html#NewlineAtEndOfFile -->
    <module name="NewlineAtEndOfFile"/>

    <!-- Checks that property files contain the same keys.         -->
    <!-- See https://checkstyle.org/config_misc.html#Translation -->
    <module name="Translation"/>

    <!-- Checks for Size Violations.                    -->
    <!-- See https://checkstyle.org/config_sizes.html -->
    <module name="FileLength"/>
    <module name="LineLength">
        <property name="max" value="120"/>
        <property name="fileExtensions" value="java"/>
    </module>

    <!-- Checks for whitespace                               -->
    <!-- See https://checkstyle.org/config_whitespace.html -->
    <module name="FileTabCharacter"/>

    <!-- Miscellaneous other checks.                   -->
    <!-- See https://checkstyle.org/config_misc.html -->
    <module name="RegexpSingleline">
        <property name="format" value="\s+$"/>
        <property name="minimum" value="0"/>
        <property name="maximum" value="0"/>
        <property name="message" value="Line has trailing spaces."/>
    </module>
    <!-- Checks for Headers                                -->
    <!-- See https://checkstyle.org/config_header.html   -->
    <!-- <module name="Header"> -->
    <!--   <property name="headerFile" value="${checkstyle.header.file}"/> -->
    <!--   <property name="fileExtensions" value="java"/> -->
    <!-- </module> -->
    <module name="TreeWalker">
        <!-- Checks for Naming Conventions.                  -->
        <!-- See https://checkstyle.org/config_naming.html -->
        <module name="ConstantName"/>
        <module name="LocalFinalVariableName"/>
        <module name="LocalVariableName"/>
        <module name="MemberName"/>
        <module name="MethodName"/>
        <module name="PackageName"/>
        <module name="ParameterName"/>
        <module name="StaticVariableName"/>
        <module name="TypeName"/>

        <!-- Checks for imports                              -->
        <!-- See https://checkstyle.org/config_import.html -->
        <module name="AvoidStarImport"/>
        <module name="IllegalImport"/> <!-- defaults to sun.* packages -->
        <module name="RedundantImport"/>
        <module name="UnusedImports">
           <!-- <property name="processJavadoc" value="false"/>-->
        </module>

        <!-- Checks for Size Violations.                    -->
        <!-- See https://checkstyle.org/config_sizes.html -->
        <module name="MethodLength"/>
        <module name="ParameterNumber"/>

        <!-- Checks for whitespace                               -->
        <!-- See https://checkstyle.org/config_whitespace.html -->
        <module name="EmptyForIteratorPad"/>
        <module name="GenericWhitespace"/>
        <module name="MethodParamPad"/>
        <module name="NoWhitespaceAfter"/>
        <module name="NoWhitespaceBefore"/>
        <module name="OperatorWrap"/>
        <module name="ParenPad"/>
        <module name="TypecastParenPad"/>
        <module name="WhitespaceAfter"/>
        <module name="WhitespaceAround"/>

        <!-- Modifier Checks                                    -->
        <!-- See https://checkstyle.org/config_modifiers.html -->
        <module name="ModifierOrder"/>
        <module name="RedundantModifier"/>

        <!-- Checks for blocks. You know, those {}'s         -->
        <!-- See https://checkstyle.org/config_blocks.html -->
        <module name="AvoidNestedBlocks"/>
        <module name="EmptyBlock"/>
        <module name="LeftCurly"/>
        <module name="NeedBraces"/>
        <module name="RightCurly"/>

        <!-- Checks for common coding problems               -->
        <!-- See https://checkstyle.org/config_coding.html -->
        <module name="EmptyStatement"/>
        <module name="EqualsHashCode"/>
<!--        <module name="HiddenField" >
            <property name="ignoreSetter" value="true" />
            <property name="ignoreConstructorParameter" value="true" />
        </module>-->
        <module name="IllegalInstantiation"/>
        <module name="InnerAssignment"/>
        <module name="MagicNumber"/>
        <module name="MissingSwitchDefault"/>
        <module name="MultipleVariableDeclarations"/>
        <module name="SimplifyBooleanExpression"/>
        <module name="SimplifyBooleanReturn"/>
        <!-- Checks for class design                         -->
        <!-- See https://checkstyle.org/config_design.html -->
<!--
        <module name="DesignForExtension"/>
-->
<!--
        <module name="FinalClass"/>
-->
      <!--  <module name="HideUtilityClassConstructor"/>-->
        <module name="InterfaceIsType"/>
        <module name="VisibilityModifier"/>

        <!-- Miscellaneous other checks.                   -->
        <!-- See https://checkstyle.org/config_misc.html -->
        <module name="ArrayTypeStyle"/>
<!--
        <module name="FinalParameters"/>
-->
        <module name="TodoComment"/>
        <module name="UpperEll"/>
        <!-- https://checkstyle.org/config_filters.html#SuppressionXpathFilter -->
        <module name="SuppressionXpathFilter">
            <property name="file" value="${org.checkstyle.sun.suppressionxpathfilter.config}"
                      default="checkstyle-xpath-suppressions.xml"/>
            <property name="optional" value="true"/>
        </module>
    </module>
</module>
```

This is my first approach to such problems and I will be grateful for a small hint where I should start to fix it.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand. You’re asking what the violated rules mean? They’re documented in the... documentation. You’re looking for where they occurred in your code? Probably depends on how you’re running it—don’t remember off hand.

Comment: Hi Dave, yes I want to know what couse the problem. I already fixed all 12 other issue but these 2 are not described on the terminal. This is the reason I  completely don't know what to do next.

Comment: By “described” do you mean the name/line of the file aren’t being shown? How are you running it?